# How to update two columns(pandas df) at once result of apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, apply

```
        ns.loc[:,'home_' + attr[2] + '_pre_game'], ns.loc[:,'away_' + attr[2] + '_pre_game'] =pd.Series(None, index=ns.index),pd.Series(None, index=ns.index)
        ns.loc[:,['home_' + attr[2] + '_pre_game','away_' + attr[2] + '_pre_game']] = ns.apply(lambda row: attr_iter(row['home_team_name'],row['away_team_name'],row[attr[0]],row[attr[1]],queues,attr[2]),axis=1)
```

I defined two new columns first and inserted empty series, with the same index as the dataframe.

I want to assign two values at once the attr_iter function returns two parameters. When I do what I do I get and error.

```
    "Must have equal len keys and value "
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

The apply function returns a series of two parametres in brackets.

Comment: It seems today was answered, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62080232/2901002), can you check ?

Comment: `ns.loc[:,['home_' + attr[2] + '_pre_game','away_' + attr[2] + '_pre_game']] = ns.apply(lambda row: attr_iter(row['home_team_name'],row['away_team_name'],row[attr[0]],row[attr[1]],queues,attr[2]),axis=1, result_type='expand')`

Comment: Thank you the solution worked for me as well. I only had to introduce the labels of the columns in the attr_iter functions.